# preg_match_all for atttach bbcode

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have two types of bbcode:
`[attach]1234[/attach]`
`[attach=full]1234[/attach]`

```
$message = 'this is message with attach [attach=full]1234[/attach]
```

I want to remove everything from string and using:

```
(preg_match_all('/\[ATTACH((.*?)\](.+?)\[\/ATTACH\]/i', $message, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER))
```

```
if (preg_match_all('/\[ATTACH((.*?)\](.+?)\[\/ATTACH\]/i', $message, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER))
{   
    for ($i=0;$i<count($out);$i++)
    {
        $replace_src[] = $out[$i][0];
        $replace_str[] = $out[$i][1];
        $newMessage = str_ireplace($replace_src, $replace_str, $message);
    }
}
```

This code remove the [attach][/attach] but not remove the [attach=full][/attach]
`=full` exsist in message.

Comment: Why don't you use `preg_replace()`?

Comment: You have an unmatched `(` in your regexp: `((.*?)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preg_replace()`, not `preg_match_all()`.

Use an optional group to match the optional `=xxx` after `attach`.

```
$newMessage = preg_replace('/\[ATTACH(?:=.*?)?\](.+?)\[\/ATTACH\]/i', '$1', $message);
```

Comment: This code not remove 1234, remove just [attach]

Comment: I thought that was what you wanted, because of the way you're using `$replace_str[] = $out[$i][1];` in your code.